# don't know why it's not redirecting properly.. how to do redirect on payments.html page with context value?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, HttpResponse
from carts.models import CartItem
from .forms import OrderForm
import datetime
from .models import Order

## Create your views here.

def payments(request):
return render(request, 'orders/payments.html')

def place_order(request, total=0, quantity=0,):
current_user = request.user

```
cart_items = CartItem.objects.filter(user=current_user)
cart_count = cart_items.count()

delivery_charge = 40
grand_total = 0
tax = 0
for cart_item in cart_items:
    total += (cart_item.product.price * cart_item.quantity)
    quantity += cart_item.quantity
tax = (2 * total)/100    
grand_total = total + tax + delivery_charge

if request.method == 'POST':
    form = OrderForm(request.POST) 
    if form.is_valid():
        data = Order()
        data.user = current_user
        data.first_name = form.cleaned_data['first_name']
        data.last_name = form.cleaned_data['last_name']
        data.phone = form.cleaned_data['phone']
        data.email = form.cleaned_data['email']
        data.address_line_1 = form.cleaned_data['address_line_1']
        data.address_line_2 = form.cleaned_data['address_line_2']
        data.country = form.cleaned_data['country']
        data.state = form.cleaned_data['state']
        data.city = form.cleaned_data['city']
        data.pincode = form.cleaned_data['pincode']
        data.order_note = form.cleaned_data['order_note']
        data.order_total = grand_total
        data.tax = tax
        data.delivery_charge = delivery_charge
        data.ip = request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR')

        yr = int(datetime.date.today().strftime('%Y'))
        dt = int(datetime.date.today().strftime('%d'))
        mt = int(datetime.date.today().strftime('%m'))
        d = datetime.date(yr,mt,dt)
        current_date = d.strftime("%Y%m%d")  # 20230214
        order_number = current_date + str(data.id)
        data.order_number = order_number
        data.save()
        
        order = Order.objects.get(user=current_user, is_ordered=False, order_number=order_number)
        context = { 'order': order, 'cart_items': cart_items, 'total': total, 'tax': tax, 'delivery_charge': delivery_charge, 'grand_total': grand_total, }
        
        return render(request, 'orders/payments.html', context)
else:
    return redirect('checkout')
```

```html
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block body %}


    <!-- Checkout Section Begin -->
    <section class="checkout spad">
        <div class="container">
            
            <form action="{% url 'place_order' %}" method="POST" class="checkout__form">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-8">
                        <h5>Billing Address Details</h5>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                                <div class="checkout__form__input">
                                    <p>First Name <span>*</span></p>
                                    <input type="text" name="first_name" placeholder="First Name" required>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                                <div class="checkout__form__input">
                                    <p>Last Name <span>*</span></p>
                                    <input type="text" name="last_name" placeholder="Last Name" required>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                                <div class="checkout__form__input">
                                    <p>Country<span>*</span></p>
                                    <input type="text" name="country" placeholder="Country Name ; e.g; India" required>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                                <div class="checkout__form__input">
                                    <p>State<span>*</span></p>
                                    <input type="text" name="state" placeholder="State Name --e.g; West Bengal" required>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                                <div class="checkout__form__input">
                                    <p>Town/City<span>*</span></p>
                                    <input type="text" name="city" placeholder="Town / Villege Name" required>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                                <div class="checkout__form__input">
                                    <p>Pincode <span>*</span></p>
                                    <input type="number" name="pincode" placeholder="Valid Pincode Address" required>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            
                            <div class="col-lg-12">
                                
                                <div class="checkout__form__input">
                                    <p>Address Line 1<span>*</span></p>
                                    <input type="text" name="address_line_1" placeholder="District, Area Name, Street Name" required>
                                </div>
                                <div class="checkout__form__input">
                                    <p>Address Line 2<span></span></p>
                                    <input type="text" name="address_line_2" placeholder="Landmark Address , Building Name ">
                                </div>
                                
                                <div class="checkout__form__input">
                                    <p>Order Note <span></span></p>
                                    <input type="text" name="order_note" placeholder=" Enter something about this order">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                                <div class="checkout__form__input">
                                    <p>Phone <span>*</span></p>
                                    <input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Valid Phone Number" required>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                                <div class="checkout__form__input">
                                    <p>Email <span>*</span></p>
                                    <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Valid Email Address" required>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            
                            
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-4">
                            <div class="checkout__order">
                                <h5>Your order</h5>
                                
                                <div class="checkout__order__product">
                                    <ul>
                                        <li>
                                            <span class="top__text">Product</span>
                                            <span class="top__text__right">Total</span>    
                                        </li>
                                         {% for cart_item in cart_items %}
                                        <li>{{ cart_item.product.product_name }} <b> [ {{ cart_item.quantity }} ]</b>
                                        <span>₹ {{ cart_item.sub_total }} </span> 
                                        <br> {% if cart_item.variations.all %} {% for item in cart_item.variations.all %} {{ item.variation_value  }} {% endfor %} {% endif %}</br> {% endfor %}
                                         </li> </ul>
                                </div>
                                <h5></h5>
                                <button type="submit" name="submit" class="site-btn "> Place Order </button>                       
                                <!-- <button type="submit" name="submit" class="site-btn"> Place Order </button>
                                <a class="site-btn submit" href="{% url 'place_order' %}"> Place Order </a> -->
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </section>
        <!-- Checkout Section End --> 
    {% endblock %}
```

Comment: Any error? or getting redirected to `checkout`?

Comment: yes it redirected to checkout.. there is an error occur while it redirecting... according to my code it should go to the next page which is payments.html with the context value if form is valid .... but it didn't redirecting to this page

Comment: `print(form.errors)` and see what is the issue.

Comment: wtf .... this one line of code is redirected to the payments page without getting error ... I don't know how .. but this line works fine ... thank you for this line ....

Comment: lol. you might have changed something and not get updated on the browser maybe cache or something. In the end, the problem is solved. :D